# How can I safely transport cooked food in warm weather?

Tags: food-safety

I've a factory of 300 people and I serve them lunch everyday. At the moment the kitchen is adjust-en with the factory but I have to move the kitchen asap to a place around 20kls. far from my factory. The big problem is I'm not sure how to deliver them from my kitchen to factory. I like to box every meal separately. At summer the temperature is 40+ C outside and my concern is will the food be safe to travel from kitchen to factory without getting spoil. Do I need refrigerated vans and if then how will I be able to warm them up ? I will be using stainless steel contains to carry the foods. Please advice.

Comment: Knowing the distance doesn't help so much as knowing the **time** it takes to cover the distance.

Comment: right you are, approx. 2 to 2 2/1 hours

Comment: Also need to know the types of foods you're moving. Coconut rice and chickpea curry with a pickle? I'd eat that if it'd been out for an hour, no problem. Chicken salad with fresh mayonnaise? No way.

Comment: The question Cindy pointed to is very relevant; the upshot is that your food is probably not safe after 2 to 2.5 hours at room temperature. However, since you've asked about some things besides just "how long is it safe?" I think this isn't exactly a duplicate.

Comment: As for the question itself, I think asking "how do I do this?" is only one of the questions you should be asking. The other is one we can't really help you with: what are the local food service regulations? Depending where you live, there may be fairly strict regulations for providing food on this scale (just as there are for restaurants), and so your first step should be finding the relevant local agencies and letting their regulations help you ensure safety.

Answer (score 1):

With all cooked, perishable food the total time in the so-called "danger zone" 40-140 °F / 4-60 °C must be minimized to avoid growing bacteria and thus food-borne illnesses. (Your transporting plans place your dishes flatly in the danger zone, so not a good idea.)

If your kitchen is on site, this is typically done by keeping food *hot* between cooking and serving. With many dishes this can be done for a short time only (a few hours maximum) before quality decreases.

If cooking off-site on a comercial scale, there is often the "cook and chill" process used. 
In short, food is cooked, then cooled down rapidly to refrigerator temperature. It is transported *cold* to the cafeteria and reheated there in special ovens, hot water bath or simply on a stove.

Prepared food can be stored for up to five days, but you need special cooling/heating equipment and cold storage/vans.
(A manufacturer's explanation [here](http://www.williams-refrigeration.com.hk/guides/the-cook-chill-process-explained).)